# Xcode Continuous Integration: Configured destination not found

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode-server, xcs

I have cloned my local repository to my Xcode server and have created a bot to run tests on each commit.

But on integration, its giving the Build Service issue : Configured destination is no longer supported or could not be found.

I was not able to find any errors from the logs either.

```
Oct 19 12:32:08  [1397] <Info>: Will attempt to update checkout cache for bot Oct 19 12:32:08  [1397] <Info>: Xcode Source Control Blueprint was valid. Oct 19 12:32:08  [1397] <Info>: About to update/checkout:   https://macbook-pro-local.com/git/SampleTestApp.git Branch: master into SampleTestCalc/  Oct 19 12:32:09  [1397] <Info>: Completed checkout of:     https://macbook-pro-local.com/git/SampleTestApp.git Branch: master (@9689116d502e2fd0f647f435f3f01597c5bd8cbd) into SampleTestCalc/  Oct 19 12:32:09  [1397] <Info>: Comparing checked out code with previous blueprint: <XCSBotSCMBlueprint 0x7f9181c25ec0>    {"DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintLocationsKey":{"D30279AB6EE6981218FC98E321E83EBACF83CAC1":{"DVTSourceControlBranchIdentifierKey":"master","DVTSourceControlLocationRevisionKey":"9689116d502e2fd0f647f435f3f01597c5bd8cbd","DVTSourceControlBranchOptionsKey":4,"DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintLocationTypeKey":"DVTSourceControlBranch"}},"DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintPrimaryRemoteRepositoryKey":"D30279AB6EE6981218FC98E321E83EBACF83CAC1","DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintIdentifierKey":"3FA96EDF-CBD4-4A8A-B42B-F05363620DF4","DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintWorkingCopyPathsKey":{"D30279AB6EE6981218FC98E321E83EBACF83CAC1":"SampleTestCalc\/"},"DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintNameKey":"SampleTestCalc","DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintVersion":204,"DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRelativePathToProjectKey":"SampleTestCalc.xcodeproj","DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoriesKey":[{"DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositorySystemKey":"com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git","DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryURLKey":"https:\/\/macbook-pro.com\/git\/SampleTestApp.git","DVTSourceControlWorkspaceBlueprintRemoteRepositoryIdentifierKey":"D30279AB6EE6981218FC98E321E83EBACF83CAC1"}]} Oct 19 12:32:09  [1397] <Info>: Got 0 log items:
```

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the Apple Guide, and am not sure what I missed. I am using Xcode8 and Server 5.2.
I also have not mentioned any destination flag anywhere in my scheme.

Answer (score 8):

Just experienced this error myself.  It was because I had selected to run the bot against all iOS simulator devices.  I simply selected one simulator and that fixed the issue.

The way to drill down further into this generic error is to do the following:

Within Xcode > 'Show the report navigator' (this is the furthest right tab bar within the left hand navigation window) > Select a failing bot run > Select 'Logs' tab from the central window > Change the 'Show' dropdown from 'Source Control log' to 'Raw build log' > This should give you more details on what went wrong to help you debug.

Comment: Thanks this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Xcode 9.2. It was resolved by deleting the developer account registered in the preferences and entering it again.