# Xcode Bot error "Configured destination is no longer supported..."

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server-bots, xcs

Xcode Server Bot, returns error of "Configured destination is no longer supported or could not be found"

when clicked "fix it", it takes me to devices, which by default it selects build for "iOS", and "IOS simulators and devices".

I tried to add an arguments to select an active simulator, but it does not help at all.

`-destination id='<simulator-id>'`

Log file shows the following errors:

```
<Error>: Could not load scheme actions record because it's missing
<Error>: XCSBuildIntegrationStep finished integration with an error: Error Domain=XCSBuildServiceDomain Code=-1 "Configured destination is no longer supported or could not be found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Configured destination is no longer supported or could not be found., XCSErrorFixItType=invalid-destination-failure}
```

I think I setup the scheme correctly by selecting `project workspace` and `Shared`. Also added script to `install cocoapods`

Comment: One possibility:  you had a device connected when you set up the XCS Bot, but when you ran this integration the device is not connected.  Verify without any destinations that are `Devices`.  That is, `Edit Bot` > `Devices` > `Build for iOS Simulators`.

Comment: @RobLabs seems that does not help. Tried to create a new pod which pointed to simulator of `iPhone 11` but still showing the same error. :(

Comment: It's also possible that one of your Simulators *has gone away*.  This can happen after upgrading from say, Xcode 11.7 to 12.0.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41446300

Comment: @RobLabs yeah but I run the command ` xcrun simctl list 'devices' 'booted' ` to get current available simulator and point destination directly to it by writing ` -destination id='<active-simulator-id>' `